K-Cycles won't render more than one blend file using the command prompt
I'm trying to render 2 different blend files in K-Cyles, frame 4 from each. This is the command I'm using:
blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\1.blend" -o //render\_# -f 4

blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\2.blend" -o //render\_## -f 4

The problem is that after it renders the first project it says Blender Quit, then has the second line of code (blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\2.blend" -o //render\_## -f 4)  just waiting for me to press enter. If I do that, it renders the second one, but I want it to do both automatically.
It's weird because every tutorial I've watched, theirs just render one after another. Why does blender quit for me, a limitation of K-Cyles?

How are you running these lines of code? Are you entering them individually or do you have them in an executable script?

If you are using Command Prompt, join the two statements with double ampersand (&&). Or if you want to ensure both commands run regardless of whether the first command succeeds or fails, use single ampersand (&):
blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\1.blend" -o //render\_# -f 4 && blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\2.blend" -o //render\_## -f 4


If you are using PowerShell, join the two statements with a semicolon to execute your command as one line:
blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\1.blend" -o //render\_# -f 4; blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\2.blend" -o //render\_## -f 4


If you want to ensure the second command only runs if the first command succeeds, use double ampersand (&&). You can also put the two commands into one script. Open notepad and paste the lines:
blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\1.blend" -o //render\_# -f 4
blender --factory-startup -b "C:\\Users\\josia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\night\_bounces\\2.blend" -o //render\_## -f 4

Then save it as .bat (if Command Prompt) or .ps1 (if PowerShell) like run_script.ps1 and execute it from the directory where you saved the file:
.\run_script.ps1


cool thanks! I'll give these things a try!

@mojojojo Cool :) Let me know how it goes. If this solved your problem kindly click the checkmark to mark it as resolved.

This is very strange! I was originally testing with a few small blend files and this was working, but then when I set up the command for my real projects it decides not to render. It gives me an insanely high render time and just keeps going higher and higher but never rendering a single tile. in the task manager the gpu never shows it's being used and the cpu fluctuates from 100% to 30%. I've tried creating the bat file too and same thing.
When I try to render each project in K-cyles I have no problem and it takes about an hour per file..??

Probably something wrong in those blend files but we unfortunately cannot diagnose this problem without any blend file. It probably will also not be feasible to share them on this site. How many blend files do you have?

There's not though, they render just fine when i open K-cycles and render from there!

I have 6 i need to render, but actually i tried rendering just that first one from the command prompt and it gives the same problem. Any ideas what could be causing it to work in gui but not cmd?

looks like it's doing it with all 6 projects individually or together.
